# MIPS Program: Number of Instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

How do I count the total number of instructions executed in the following MIPS program?

```
      ADDI R1, R0, #1
      SW R1, 2000 (R0)
LOOP: LW R1, 2000 (R0)
      MULT R2, R1, #4
      ADDI R3,R2, #5000
      LW R4, 0 (R3)
      LW R5, 1500 (R0)
      ADD R6, R4, R5
      LW R1, 2000 (R0)
      MULT R2, R1, #4
      ADDI R1, R1, #1
      SW R6, 0(R7)
      SW R1, 2000 (R0)
      ADDI R1, R1, #1
      SW R1, 2000 (R0)
      ADDI R1, R1, #1
      LW R1, 2000 (R0)
      ADDI R8, R1, #-101
      BNEZ R8, LOOP
```